# PANDAS - Plotting specific rows and changing order of columns

Tags: python, plot, pandas, dataframe

I have the following df

```
        PARTS
status  Amber   Red White   Yellow
SELECTOR                
BOTDWG   2652    8453    1577    4636
STRSUB   387     1236    218     595
```

I want to plot two bar charts. One for each of the rows BOTDWG & STRSUB but I want the bars to be in a different order to that in the df. I need Red, Amber, Yellow White.

Any ideas how I can do this?

Thanks
Simon

Comment: here is [matplotlib's barchart documentation](http://matplotlib.org/users/screenshots.html#bar-charts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I'd drop the first level of the multi-index (the one with PARTS)*:

```
df1.columns = df1.columns.droplevel(0)

In [12]: df1
Out[12]:
status    Amber   Red  White  Yellow
SELECTOR
BOTDWG     2652  8453   1577    4636
STRSUB      387  1236    218     595
```

Then do a (bar) plot:

```
df1.plot(kind='bar')
```

To change the order, I'd probably do something like:

```
df1['Red Amber Yellow White'.split()].plot(kind='bar')
# equivalently:  df1[['Red', 'Amber', 'Yellow', 'White']].plot(kind='bar')
```

** that way it'll print just Amber (rather than the tuple (PARTS, Amber) etc.)*

Comment: Thanks for this, it worked. But I found that i could not do the drop level df1.columns = df1.columns.droplevel(0) as you specified. I had to do this instead df2.columns = df1.columns.droplevel(0)

Comment: @PrestonDocks that's interesting... perhaps we had slightly different df1/df2s, glad you got it working! :)